# Load file with environment variables Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

I am doing a simple pipeline:

*Build -> Staging -> Production*

I need different environment variables for staging and production, so i am trying to *source* variables.

```
sh 'source $JENKINS_HOME/.envvars/stacktest-staging.sh'
```

But it returns *Not found*

```
[Stack Test] Running shell script
+ source /var/jenkins_home/.envvars/stacktest-staging.sh
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/Stack Test@tmp/durable-bcbe1515/script.sh: 2: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Stack Test@tmp/durable-bcbe1515/script.sh: source: not found
```

The path is right, because i run the same command when i log via ssh, and it works fine.

Here is the pipeline idea:

```
node {
    stage name: 'Build'
    // git and gradle build OK
    echo 'My build stage'

    stage name: 'Staging'
    sh 'source $JENKINS_HOME/.envvars/stacktest-staging.sh' // PROBLEM HERE
    echo '$DB_URL' // Expects http://production_url/my_db
    sh 'gradle flywayMigrate' // To staging
    input message: "Does Staging server look good?"    

    stage name: 'Production'
    sh 'source $JENKINS_HOME/.envvars/stacktest-production.sh'
    echo '$DB_URL' // Expects http://production_url/my_db
    sh 'gradle flywayMigrate' // To production
    sh './deploy.sh'
}
```

What should i do?

- I was thinking about not using pipeline (but i will not be able to use my Jenkinsfile).
- Or make different jobs for staging and production, using EnvInject Plugin (But i lose my stage view)
- Or make withEnv (but the code gets big, because today i am working with 12 env vars)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

One way you could load environment variables from a file is to load a Groovy file.

For example:

1. Let's say you have a groovy file in '$JENKINS_HOME/.envvars' called 'stacktest-staging.groovy'.
2. Inside this file, you define 2 environment variables you want to load

   ```
   env.DB_URL="hello"
   env.DB_URL2="hello2"
   ```
3. You can then load this in using

   ```
   load "$JENKINS_HOME/.envvars/stacktest-staging.groovy"
   ```
4. Then you can use them in subsequent echo/shell steps.

For example, here is a short pipeline script:

```
node {
   load "$JENKINS_HOME/.envvars/stacktest-staging.groovy"
   echo "${env.DB_URL}"
   echo "${env.DB_URL2}"
}
```

Comment: Please notice that using the env variable is discouraged, as the env variable is global. The recommended practice would be to load local variables, and then eventually set them as environment variables if needed in a part of a pipeline by using the `withEnv` construct.

Comment: @stoned how can i use a password with withEnv and Jenkinsfile? (without expose my password on Jenkinsfile, because i don't want it on git repository). Is there a way without `load "myenvvars.groovy"`.

Comment: @Rafael you could use the credentials binding plugin, which will add a "withCredentials" pipeline function which allows to pass credentials stored in Jenkins's credentials stores. If the credentials are static, you could also look at the maskpassword plugin. You could even consider to use a third party service to store credentials, such as HasciCorp Vault which got its own plugin and relative pipeline function.

Comment: @stoned thanks. That works fine. Here is a [credential plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin). "From a Pipeline job, define your credentials, then check Snippet Generator for a syntax example of the withCredentials step"

Comment: why "env." is necessary ? because I have tried without and it did not work

Comment: A word of warning: If you use 'load "somefile.groovy"', your file will be ignored if you use Replay to start your pipeline. Replay replaces the contents of your groovy files with the code submitted for replay, and thus you will get the environment variables from the previous run, not the latest one. This might not be an issue for you, but be aware that if the file has any possibility of being modified between executions that such changes will be ignored.

Comment: It is not working for me. I am getting following error when I put load in node{} block: 
 WorkflowScript: 7: Invalid config option "load" for agent type "node". Valid config options are [label, customWorkspace] @ line 7, column 13.

Comment: WARNING: loading a file with `env.` variables silently converts ALL values to the `String` type. So if you think you're being smart by adding a `Map` type (`env.x = ['a':1, 'b':2]`), using that in the Jenkinsfile, you're screwing yourself. You can use `env.` for your actual env vars, and then just `x = ['a':1, 'b':2]; return this` (`return this` is added as the last line), and then `def my_vals = load 'my_file'; my_vals.x['a']` in the Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 29):

From the comments to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39178479/6104519)

Don't use global 'env' but use 'withEnv' construct, eg see:
issue #9: don't set env vars with global env in [top 10 best practices jenkins pipeline plugin](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/top-10-best-practices-jenkins-pipeline-plugin)

In the following example: VAR1 is a plain java string (no groovy variable expansion), VAR2 is a groovy string (so variable 'someGroovyVar' is expanded).

The passed script is a plain java string, so $VAR1 and $VAR2 are passed literally to the shell, and the echo's are accessing environment variables VAR1 and VAR2.

```
stage('build') {
    def someGroovyVar = 'Hello world'
    withEnv(['VAR1=VALUE ONE',
             "VAR2=${someGroovyVar}"
            ]) {
        def result = sh(script: 'echo $VAR1; echo $VAR2', returnStdout: true)
        echo result
    }
}
```

For secrets / passwords you can use [credentials binding plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin)

Example:

NOTE: CREDENTIALS_ID1 is a registered username/password secret on the Jenkins settings.

```
stage('Push') {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(
                         credentialsId: 'CREDENTIALS_ID1',
                         passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD',
                         usernameVariable: 'USER')]) {
        echo "User name: $USER"
        echo "Password:  $PASSWORD"
    }
}
```

The jenkisn console log output hides the real values:

```
[Pipeline] echo
User name: ****
[Pipeline] echo
Password:  ****
```

Jenkins and credentials is a big issue, probably see: [credentials plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin)

For completeness: Most of the time, we need the secrets in environment variables, as we use them from shell scripts, so we combine the withCredentials and withEnv like follows:

```
stage('Push') {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword(
                         credentialsId: 'CREDENTIALS_ID1',
                         passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD',
                         usernameVariable: 'USER')]) {
        withEnv(["ENV_USERNAME=${USER}",
                 "ENV_PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}"
            ]) {
                def result = sh(script: 'echo $ENV_USERNAME', returnStdout: true)
                echo result

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For what its worth- I was able to reference the credentials as shell env vars without adding them in the `withEnv` step.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. But `withEnv` is local to only the step, while env var is global. (that's the point of issue #9: don't set env vars with global env).

Answer (score 13):

With **declarative** pipeline, you can do it in one line ( change `path` by your value):

```
script {
  readProperties(file: path).each {key, value -> env[key] = value }
}
```

Comment: Where would you put this? You can't use staticMethods inside steps (at least for declaritive pipelines in Jenkins 2.176).

Comment: @SCote i have already surrounded the step with "script" step. Then, it should work within declarative pipeline : `steps  { ... put it here ... }`

Answer (score 12):

Another way to resolve this install 'Pipeline Utility Steps' plugin  that  provides us  readProperties  method ( for reference please go to the link https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#pipeline-utility-steps)
Here in the example we can see that they are storing the keys into an array and using the keys to retrieve the value. 
   But in that case the in production the problem will be like  if we add any variable later into property file that variable needs to be added into the array of Jenkins file as well.
   To get rid of this tight coupling, we can write code in such a way so that the Jenkins build environment can get information automatically about all the existing keys which presents currently in the Property file. Here is an example for the reference

```
def loadEnvironmentVariables(path){
    def props = readProperties  file: path
    keys= props.keySet()
    for(key in keys) {
        value = props["${key}"]
        env."${key}" = "${value}"
    }
}
```

And the client code looks like

```
path = '\\ABS_Output\\EnvVars\\pic_env_vars.properties'
loadEnvironmentVariables(path)
```

Answer (score 9):

Using withEnv() to pass environment variables from file splitted by new line and casted to List:

```groovy
writeFile file: 'version.txt', text: 'version=6.22.0'
withEnv(readFile('version.txt').split('\n') as List) {
    sh "echo ${version}"
}
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution for me, nice and easy, thank you!

Comment: To remove possible empty lines in the version.txt file: readFile('version.txt').replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "").split('\n')

Comment: @gogo_gorilla, Also, you might prepare your env.list to find all strings containing equal character:
def list = ['version=6.22.0', '  ', '', 'text 123']
list.findAll { it.contains('=') }​​​​​​​

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Jenkins 2.0 you can load the property file (which consists of all required Environment variables along with their corresponding values) and read all the environment variables listed there automatically and inject it into the Jenkins provided env entity.

Here is a method which performs the above stated action.

```
def loadProperties(path) {
    properties = new Properties()
    File propertiesFile = new File(path)
    properties.load(propertiesFile.newDataInputStream())
    Set<Object> keys = properties.keySet();
    for(Object k:keys){
    String key = (String)k;
    String value =(String) properties.getProperty(key)
    env."${key}" = "${value}"
    }
}
```

To call this method we need to pass the path of property file as a string variable For example, in our Jenkins file using groovy script we can call like

```
path = "${workspace}/pic_env_vars.properties"
loadProperties(path)
```

Please ask me if you have any doubt

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete example of externalizing environment variables and loading them in Jenkins pipeline execution. The pipeline is written in a [declarative style](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/).

```
stage('Reading environment variable defined in groovy file') {
            steps {
                script {
                    load "./pipeline/basics/extenvvariable/env.groovy"
                    echo "${env.env_var1}"
                    echo "${env.env_var2}"
                }
            }
        }
```

Complete code example:
https://github.com/dhruv-bansal/jenkins-pipeline-exploration/blob/master/pipeline/basics/extenvvariable/Jenkinsfile

Where variables are loaded from a groovy file placed with the pipeline code only.
https://github.com/dhruv-bansal/jenkins-pipeline-exploration/blob/master/pipeline/basics/extenvvariable/env.groovy

This pattern comes very handy when you are creating a generic pipeline that could be used across teams.
You can externalize the dependent variable in such groovy file and each team can define their values according to their ecosystem.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use a custom method without allowing extra permissions such as for `new Properties()` which leads to this error before allowing:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.util.Properties
```

or adding extra plugin methods such as `readProperties`.

here is a method which reads a simple file named `env_vars` in this format:

```
FOO=bar
FOO2=bar
```

```
pipeline {
<... skipped lines ...>
    script {
        loadEnvironmentVariablesFromFile("env_vars")

        echo "show time! ${BAR} ${BAR2}"
    }
<... skipped lines ...>
}

private void loadEnvironmentVariablesFromFile(String path) {
    def file = readFile(path)
    file.split('\n').each { envLine ->
        def (key, value) = envLine.tokenize('=')
        env."${key}" = "${value}"
    }
}
```