# Environment variables are not found in Jenkins

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, environment-variables

I want to set quite a few variables in Jenkins. I have tried putting them in `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and `.profile` of the `jenkins` user but Jenkins cannot find them when a build is happening.

The only way that is working is to put all the env variables inside the `Jenkinsfile` like this:

```
env.INTERCOM_APP_ID = '12312'
env.INTERCOM_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN = '1231'
env.INTERCOM_IDENTITY_VERIFICATION_KEY='asadfas'
```

But I don't think this is a good way of doing it.

What is the correct way of setting env variables in Jenkins?

Comment: Are you using Amazon Linux AMI?

Comment: @TalhaJunaid No, I am using GCP compute instance.

Comment: Previously I faced this issue using Amazon Linux  AMI it flushes out the environment variables after a restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it seems very normal. `INTERCOM_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN` and `INTERCOM_IDENTITY_VERIFICATION_KEY` should be considered as text credentials and you can use the [`environment`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment)  directive to add environment variables.

```
stages {
    stage('Example') {
        environment {
            INTERCOM_APP_ID = '12312'
            INTERCOM_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN = credentials('TokenCrednetialsID')
            INTERCOM_IDENTITY_VERIFICATION_KEY = credentials('VerificationCrednetialsID')
        }
        steps {
            echo "Hello ${env.INTERCOM_APP_ID}"
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to keep environment variables separate from `JenkinsFile` you can create a groovy file which contains all of those and then load that file into `Jenkinsfile` using

```
load "$JENKINS_HOME/.envvars/stacktest-staging.groovy"
```

For more information take a look at following links

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/

[SO: Load file with environment variables ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39178479/3358570)

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution because I have lots of env variables, not just three. I don't want them to occupy most of my Jenkinsfile

Comment: Setting Jenkins specific environment variables at the system level is dangerous as it contains secret texts as well. You can create a groovy file which contains and load that into jenkinsFile. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39178479/3358570. to learn how to do that.

Comment: Yup. That's what I needed. If you add it to your answer, I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins resets environment variables to some defaults for their jobs. Best way to set them is in jenkins configuration. You can set global vars, local for project or local for node.

Now i do not remember if this feature is build in or provided by some plugin.