# Access Jenkins credential store secrets with env groovy file

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I've implemented loading a groovy file for env variables by following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51414302/environment-variables-are-not-found-in-jenkins).

**env.groovy:**

```
env.DB_USER = 'testuser'
env.DB_PASS = credentials('DB_PASS')
```

**Jenkinsfile**:

```
stages {
    stage ("print") {
        steps {
            load "${WORKSPACE}/env.groovy"
            echo "${env.DB_USER}"
            echo "${env.DB_PASS}"
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Pipeline] echo
testuser
[Pipeline] echo
@credentials(<anonymous>=DB_PASS)
```

Is accessing the Jenkins credential store possible for DB_PASS when loading a groovy env variable file?

Note: I know I can access the environment variables in the environment { } block of my Jenkinsfile. But since I have so many env variables, I was wondering if I could reference them all in a separate groovy file instead.

Comment: So you want your  echo "${env.DB_PASS}"  statement to actually print out the password?

Comment: Well, yes for the time being to see if it works. Normally it would just mask the password like this ******. But I've never seen it print @credentials(<anonymous>=DB_PASS) out which made me think accessing the credential store isn't working.

Comment: I think it's because credentials('credential_id') is to be used inside jenkinsfile to get the desired behaviour.  The syntax is not for use in a groovy file.  I'm trying to  get my jenkins up. I'll update if I figure out something.

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, try to do it like this inside your jenkinsfile.

```
environment {
            DB_PASS = credentials('DB_PASS')
        }
```

However you still can't echo your DB_PASS environment variable since credentials type variables retain the property of secrecy. And also keep in mind that variables have scope in jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
environment {
            DB_PASS = credentials('DB_PASS')
        }
```

If you really would like to see the contents of that
you could do

```
  sh """
     echo "$DB_PASS" | base64
                    
     """
```

That will show you the secret, hope this helps.