# How to source bash script in Jenkins Pipeline enviornment section

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an existing bash script that just sets about 100 variables, e.g. paths, version numbers etc. that we source as part as the first part of all our build jobs.
I'm moving some of these build jobs to jenkins pipelines and am trying to find if there is a way to source the variables from that file inside the jenkins environment stage so it can be used throughout the build pipeline's subsequent steps.

I feel like I'm missing something as I'm not really familiar with groovy.
i think maybe using System.getenv, but that requires they are set, and I think sourcing it in a sh script block doesnt' persist.

Below is what I am wroking with but doesn't work (though gives a conceptual idea.)

any advice would be appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
agent {label "${params.VM_to_use}"}

    environment {
        TARGET_VM = "${params.VM_to_use}"
        //I'd like to be able to access vars globally or if better way I'm up for it.
    }

    stages {
        stage ('Get vars in preperation for subsequent build steps...'){
            steps {
                sh '''
                    source /net/machine1/globalvars/functions/my_global_vars.sh
                    # product_123_version number in that file.
                '''
                script {
                    currentBuild.displayName = " ${env.product_123_version} - ${TARGET_VM}"
                    currentBuild.displayName = System.getenv("TESTVAR")
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Build Step 2...'){
            steps {
                sh '''
                    # pass version to script...
                    /build_step_2.sh ${env.product_123_version}

                '''

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to load ( or source file in jenkins):-

1. Using [load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171341/load-file-with-environment-variables-jenkins-pipeline) function of jenkins ( used to load file from local path )
2. Using [fileLoader](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-remote-loader-plugin/blob/master/README.md) function ( used to load file located at remote location i.e. any SCM only  file with .groovy extension will be loaded)

The file should contains (loadFile.sh or loadFile.groovy) the data as below:-

```
// Comments should start like this one
env.Location='Pune'
env.Day='Friday'
env.Job_UI='Jenkins'
```

You can use the below code with some modifications:-

```
stages {
           stage('Load') {    
              agent { node { label 'master' } }
                steps {
                  script {
                    // From the below two lines of code, you can use the one suits your need better
                    // def localenv = fileLoader.fromGit ("./Vars/loadFile.sh", "GITURL", 'BRANCH_NAME', 'Credentials', '')
                       load '/u/users/admin/loadFile.sh'
                            }
                        }
                    }    
           stage('Print') {    
              agent { node { label 'master' } }
                steps {
                   script {
                              echo "Location :- ${env.Location}"
                              echo "Day :- ${env.Day}"
                              echo "Job :- ${env.Job_UI}"
                          }
                       }
                 }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this useful information!

While it might be user error on my part, the workflow provided doesn't seem to be able to load bash scripts, or at least, it wouldn't work with mine as it's trying to interpret comments starting with # as something and fails to load.
I think for this to work I'd have to change the script by removing the #comments.
For exmaple it is trying to load myGlobalVars.sh and returns

Script1.groovy: 3: unexpected char: '#' @ line 3, column 1.

Comment: As jenkins considers that the file you are loading is groovy, you need to put comments using "//" not "#", updated in answer!

Comment: For your case you can replace "#" with "//"

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. This answer should be accepted.