# How to use inject environment variables (Properties File Path) in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Want to use the below functionality(shown in image link) in Jenkins as code, but i'm failing to do, kindly help me replicate the functionality in the image to groovy script

```
stage ('Build Instance') {
        sh ''' 
          bash ./build.sh -Ddisable-rpm=false
           ''' 
        env "/fl/tar/ver.prop" 
          }
```

[Jenkins GUI usage of Env Inject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKxkk.png)

Comment: EnvInject plugin is not compatible with Pipeline as a Code - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42614

Comment: Thanks for reply @SzymonStepniak, is there any work around for the above scenario, though i did see one on the issues page.

Comment: You can use the below answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171341/load-file-with-environment-variables-jenkins-pipeline

Comment: @chetan.vatharkar Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got a simple workaround :

```
   script {
                def props = readProperties file: '/fl/tar/ver.prop' //readProperties is a step in Pipeline Utility Steps plugin
                env.WEATHER = props.WEATHER //assuming the key name is WEATHER in properties file
            }
```