# how to store variables in jenkins for e2e testing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, e2e-testing, dotenv

I'm using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for storing my test usernames and pwrds.
Example:
.env content examples:

```
TEST_CONTENT_PWRD="123456"
```

.ts content use example:

```
const TEST_USR_LOOKUP: {[type:string]: TESTUser } = {
  USERA:{
    username: "testABC", 
    pwrd: process.env.TEST_CONTENT_PWRD
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is add the values in JENKINS so that the values can be pulled in during the E2E step in the pipeline.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `load` to setup variables from your `.env` file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171341/load-file-with-environment-variables-jenkins-pipeline) you can find more information this solution.